# highcharts - how do I do custom labels on heatmap legend

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Here is a jsfiddle of my chart:

http://jsfiddle.net/b637gdxv/4/

```
    chart: {
        type: 'heatmap',
        marginTop: 26,
        marginLeft: 5,
        marginRight: 5,

        width: 200, 
        height: 250,

        borderWidth: 3,
        borderColor: 'grey',
        borderRadius: 5,
        plotBackgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
        plotShadow: true
    },
```

Currently I am unable to figure out how to add custom labels to this chart. I don't want the '0-100' labels, instead I want to have the text 'Free' on the very left and 'Full' on the very right. What do I need to do to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can configure labels in the colorAxis config.

```
colorAxis: {
  min: 0,
  max: 100,
  stops: [
    [0, '#9DFF9D'],
    [0.2, '#fffbbc'],
    [0.7, '#fffbbc'],
    [0.9, '#E6532E']
  ],
  labels: {
    step: 4,
    enabled: true,
    formatter: function() {
      return this.value === 0 ? "Free" : "Full";
    }
  }
}
```

Here's the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/b637gdxv/5/

Note that I'm not really sure how highcharts figures out how many ticks the colorAxis will draw, but going off your example 4 was the right number to get it to only show the first and last labels.

Also just a heads up, the formatter function will set the 0 tick to "Free" and all the others to "Full", but since here you only show 2 ticks it works out.

Highcharts actually has a pretty awesome api with fiddle examples for most config options, so you can check out the other options for labels and anything else here:

http://api.highcharts.com/highmaps#colorAxis.labels

Comment: Thanks! I wish I knew of better documentation on highcharts formatters online. My original jquery's legend bar was too wide - fixing this proved a little tricky. For anyone who has a similar issue, you have to set `legend{ symbolWidth: 100 }` and change `step: 4` to `step: 2`